# Why didn't Voyager offer antimatter purification processes to other Malon vessels?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In *Night*, where Voyager first encounters the Malon, they attempt to give Emck a technology that will enable the Malon to purify antimatter, thus avoiding the hazardous waste dumping process. Emck declines, saying that would lose him too much profit — he has a way to dump the waste that's much cheaper than other vessels, the void from the episode.

Evidently, Voyager ends up running into Malon multiple additional times, ships that don't have Emck's advantage over others. Why doesn't Voyager offer them the antimatter tech?

Comment: I’ve just watched these episodes myself and it’s clear the Malon aren’t interested anyway. One ship flew into a gas giant and was destroyed rather than heed Voyager’s warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no proof they didn't, just as there is no proof they did offer the technology to others.**

Possible reasons for others declining the offer, just as Emck, are as follows:

**The dumping might still be highly profitable,** even without Emck's distinct advantage.There is no reason to believe, that other Malon should not follow the same reasoning of (albeit smaller) profit over safety.

<del>Even more so, as the process is - as far as I remember - not so much a risk to life and limb, but - due to medical treatment - only disfigures the dumper crews.</del> [I did my research after a comment by Daniel B. - I apologize in advance for only including Memory Alpha sources!]

Even though there is some treatment, the transport is still highly risky, especially for the ["core laborers"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Core_laborer), which have only a 30% chance of surviving a typical mission. **The compensation is very high (up to several lifetime earnings for other professions), though, and is paid to the family of non-surviving crew members**. **This provides for very high individual economical incentive to continue this trade.**

**The scars, that surviving crew bear, could very well be viewed as a badge of honor,** [as the bearers evidently did provide a vital service to society](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Waste_export_industry). This could further diminish the possible gain of getting a safe alternative, at least in the short term. **This adds a non-monetary incentive to continuing the dumping trade.**

Comment: Actually, it's incredibly dangerous — apparently, out of the crew working close to the tanks, there's only a 30% survival rate per mission.

Comment: @DanielB I fixed my wrong claim of only cosmetic damages to waste haulers. - The argument still holds, in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think this answer really covers my issues with the episode, but I'll take it.

Answer (score 1):

The Malon serve as examples for shrewd businesses with limited environmental conscience. Unlike the Federation, the Malon appear to have a barter/money society thus the recycling of their anti-matter waste may be still an expensive process whether voyager gave them the technology or not. The Malon were never seen again past season 5, thus it might be established their government was warned about the dangers their waste poses. Voyager may have done that and warned the last malon ship they encountered in the episode "Juggernaut". The Malon may also have simply sold the waste to a society that finds a good use for it (Trash to Treasure). In Voyager's case, A simple trade agreement could have been established with Voyager taking the waste and converting it into fuel.